# What's the fourth term in the multivariable Taylor expansion?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

For a function $f: \Bbb R^n \to R$, the $2$nd order Taylor expansion is:

$$f(\mathbf x+\mathbf h) \approx f(\mathbf x)+ Df(\mathbf x) \mathbf h + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf h^T H(f)(\mathbf x) \mathbf h$$

What's the next term (the last term in the $3$rd order Taylor expansion)?

I can see that $Df(\mathbf x)$ is a row vector, so to make it scalar, we need to right multiply a column vector.  And similarly $Hf(\mathbf x)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix so to make it a scalar we need to left and right multiply by vectors (row and column, respectively).  I can't think what the next term would have to be, though.

Comment: As you probably expect, it involves the third partial derivatives, with some smoothness assumptions guaranteeing "symmetry" of the associated $n\times n\times n$ multilinear object.

Comment: It takes an "hypermatrix" ($3D$) to represent that, i.e. a tensor. For compactness you have to switch to Einstein's notation, like$$
f(x) = f(0) + (\partial_{i} f)(0) x_i + \frac{1}{2!} (\partial_{ij} f)(0) x_i x_j + \frac{1}{3!} (\partial_{ijk} f)(0) x_i x_j x_k + ...$$

Comment: A convenient way of writing the Taylor series in any dimension is $f(x+h)=e^{h\cdot\nabla}f(x)$. Expand the series formally in powers of $h$ and then apply the derivatives to $f$ at $x$; you will get the Taylor polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

The next term is

$$
\frac{1}{3!}D^3f\big|_x(h,h,h)
$$

Where

$$
D^3f\big|_x = \sum \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j \partial x_k} dx_i \otimes dx_j \otimes dx_k
$$

In other words, the third term is

$$
\frac{1}{3!}\sum \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j \partial x_k} h_i h_j h_k
$$

Comment: You may be interested in the online course here: http://ximera.osu.edu/course/kisonecat/m2o2c2/course/ which I wrote.  It covers all the needed multivariable calculus and multilinear algebra to understand the multivariable taylor's theorem.

Comment: @PawelKranzberg Indeed, and sorry about that.  I don't think I can resurrect the site at this point, but I might be able to at least compile the pdfs.  This might happen this summer...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: onpoint. Dunno why its always tought with Mulinomialcoefficients and those ugly multi-potencys etc. This is the way to think of derivatives in higher dimensions.