# Multivariable differentiation rules and notation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, notation, vector-analysis, jacobian

I have $y:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\dot y = f(y)$.
And I have the differentiation with respect to the arguement of $y$:
\begin{align*}
\dot y &= f(y) \\
\ddot y &= f’(y)\dot y \quad\quad& \text{step  2}\\
y^{(3)} &= f’’(y)(\dot y, \dot y) + f'(y)\ddot y \quad\quad& \text{step  3}\\
y^{(4)} &= f’’’(y)(\dot y, \dot y,\dot y) + 3f’’(y)(\ddot y, \dot y) + f’(y)y^{(3)}\quad\quad& \text{step  4}
\end{align*}

My question is:

1. What is $f’’’(y)(\dot y, \dot y,\dot y)$ in matrix form? I don't understand the notation and how it works.
2. What are the rules governing this differentiation? How does one go from step 2 to step 3 to step 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule for vector differentiation is a bit more complicated than that for scalar functions since you need to ensure the dimensions of each multiplication are well defined. For instance, suppose $\dot{y}(t) = f(y(t))$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dt}\dot{y}_i(t) = \frac{d}{dt} f_i(y(t)) = \nabla_y f_i(y(t))^\top \dot{y}(t) ~ \text{for $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$}.
\end{equation*}
Compactly, we have that
\begin{equation*}
\ddot{y}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \nabla_y f_1(y(t))^\top \\ \nabla_y f_2(y(t))^\top \\ \vdots \\ \nabla_y f_n(y(t))^\top \end{bmatrix} \dot{y}(t) = Df(y(t)) \dot{y}(t),
\end{equation*}
where $Df$ is the Jacobian of $f$. Taking another derivative,
\begin{gather*}
\frac{d}{dt}\ddot{y}_i(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\nabla_y f_i(y(t))^\top \dot{y}(t) = \left(\frac{d}{dt} \nabla_y f_i(y(t))\right)^\top\dot{y}(t) + \nabla_{y} f_i(y(t))^\top \ddot{y}(t) \\
= \left( \nabla^2_y f_i(y(t)) \dot{y}(t) \right)^\top \dot{y}(t) + \nabla_y f_i(y(t))^\top \ddot{y}(t) \\
= \dot{y}(t)^\top \nabla^2_y f(y(t)) \dot{y}(t) + \nabla_y f_i(y(t))^\top \ddot{y}(t),
\end{gather*}
for $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Now, since the Hessian $\nabla_y^2 f_i(y(t))$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, there is not really a simple method for combining the above equations into a vector equation for $\frac{d}{dt}\ddot{y}(t)$ without introducing tensors or bi-linear forms.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Do you know of any resource that included both an intro to tensors and an explanation of Taylor's in higher dimensions? I found a lot of tensor books but most don't include anything about Taylor's.

Comment: I did a quick search and it looks like more references write multivariate Taylor's theorem up to the second-order term then put $\dots$ haha! One way to avoid the use of tensors is to write things in summation notation. For instance see the answer here for a summation form of the third-order term: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1059378/whats-the-fourth-term-in-the-multivariable-taylor-expansion

Comment: Notice that the $i$th-order term in the Taylor series includes a sum over $i$ indices. This is why we can represent the second-order term succinctly using matrices (since they have two indices), but with higher orders we must start introducing new notations/definitions to capture the summation over more indices. Also, if your function maps $m$-vectors to $n$-vectors, the formulas become even more complicated and the number of indices you must sum over grows even faster than just $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks again, I actually understand how it works now. I realise you don't actually need tensors, just multilinear forms that I actually covered in a class that involved some exterior algebra.